# SSH behind VPN - How to protect VPN?

Tags: ssh, openvpn

I am quite aware of SSH brute-force attacks. I set up everything I can: fail2ban, no root login, only public authentification on WAN. However I am still spammed in my logs and fail2ban has a increasing number of IP which consumes my CPU, RAM and bandwidth. While this is still not a big issue, I have chosen to use the last power : Shutdown SSH on WAN and only allow it on LAN.
For this, I have implemented OpenVPN that only serves to give access to LAN so we can still access the device anywhere.

Of course, as the firewall is dropping external packets, I have no more SSH bruteforce and I haven't found any attack on my VPN but I wanna wondering, how can I protect my VPN? Is it necessary ? And how to do it?
I have tls-crypt enabled. OpenVPN manual said about tls-auth and tls-crypt:

> Add an additional layer of HMAC authentication on top of the TLS control channel to mitigate DoS attacks and attacks on the TLS stack.In a nutshell, --tls-auth enables a kind of "HMAC firewall" on OpenVPN's TCP/UDP port, where TLS control channel packets bearing an incorrect HMAC signature can be dropped immediately without response.

Is this enough? or should I use something else? This is my configuration (use only of certificates I create from my own CA) :

```
port 3084
proto udp
dev tun
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
keepalive 10 120
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.0.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
#push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
#push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
#push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
#route-nopull
push "route 192.168.0.0 255.255.0.0"
dh none
ecdh-curve prime256v1
tls-crypt tls-crypt.key
#crl-verify crl.pem
ca fullchain.crt
cert cert-server.pem
key server-key.pem
auth SHA256
cipher AES-256-GCM
ncp-ciphers AES-256-GCM
tls-server
tls-version-min 1.2
#tls-cipher TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
status /var/log/openvpn/status.log
log-append /var/log/openvpn/openvpn.log
verb 3
```

NB : I have found my solution. I have blocked my port on ipv4 and only allow ipv6. As I have a domain and a AAAA block, I can connect using the DNS but as ipv6 is far beyond actual machines performance to scan (10^38 instead of 4 billion for ipv4), there is absolutely no attempt to connect to SSH. So with a decent protection, it will avoid you to be spammed in logs.

Comment: Or you could have changed the default SSH port. That's how I decreased the number of attacks 1000-fold.

Comment: I already did too and it clearly did not work that much (just 2 or 3 fold at most), there are probably using nmap. And after some hours, still dozens or even hundreds of banned IP and bruteforce.

Comment: VPN first and SSH with private key only, seems a very good protection. In adition to that, Have you tried also increasing the bantime in fail2ban? I have a default of 1 week bantime.  This works really well for me.

Comment: But if VPN is compromised it would expose my LAN and therefore would be a major security issue. My fail to ban is 10 mn then 50 mn then 8h. If I upgrade it, fail2ban would have more IP so more CPU no?

Comment: You need to work your threat model math a bit more: chances of brute forcing a private key are... Small. The expected time it takes is measured in 10s of thousands to millions of years. You adding anything to reduce that likelihood has absolutely no significant security effect at all. Brute forcing a random 256 bit key over network will just not happen in the internet's existence. What does happen is dictionary attacks on human-chosen passwords, and these typically happen from the thousands to millions of IP addresses of botnets, each bot only trying few passwords.Against that, fail2ban fails.

Comment: So, disabling passwords has meaningful security effect. Using fail2ban has meaningful performance and thus availability effect - you're blocking requests from bots after a few failed attempts at low resource cost, so that they move on and pester someone else, leaving your resources available for the device you actually want to run.